# Post запрос возвращает Internal server error

Tags: php, java, android

Пытаюсь отправить на сайт Post запрос, вот код:

```
URL urlObj = null;
urlObj = new URL("https://mysite");
JSONObject auth = new JSONObject();
auth.put("email", email);
auth.put("password", password);
auth.put("remember", remember);

HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");


conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(auth.toString());
```

Сайт возвращает Internal server error. 
Вот что по идее должно быть:

```
 POST https://mysite/auth/login HTTP/1.1
 Host: mysite
 Connection: keep-alive
 Content-Length: 70
 Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
 Origin: https://mysite
 X-XSRF-TOKEN: .............
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Referer: https://mysite/login
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,es;q=0.2
 Cookie: _ym_uid=.....; _ym_isad=1; _gat=1; _ga=GA....; XSRF-TOKEN=....; laravel_session=....
```

(Точки - очень много текста вида "G5QV0FJS3ZkMkJ2UUE9PSI")
Помогите пожалуйста правильно настроить отправку post запроса.
Сайт на Laravel + Angular.

Comment: ну так сказано же: внутренняя ошибка сервера, а вы показывает код клиента. Код php покажите

Comment: Проблема в том что у меня есть серверная часть, но в php я ничего не понимаю. Get запросы, кстати, правильно возвращают JSON.

Comment: Что в логах ошибок веб сервера? В логах Laravel?

Comment: на то она и *внутренняя* ошибка сервера, что нужно спрашивать у серверного разработчика, что не так.